# Confused by Python find_element_by_id Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This should be a seemingly simple problem-

Python v3.10.6, Selenium v4.7.2

I'm attempting the most basic of webcrawling activities...but find_element_by_id (or any other find element methods for that matter) are returning a "AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'" error

Trying to (at first) just click the help botton at https://www.mouser.com/
Am getting that element ID as "aHelp":

[image: Help Button ID]

The code:

[image: Code]

I always get this Attribute Error...
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium's newer versions no longer support using `driver.find_element_by_*`.
try `driver.find_element(By.ID, "the id you want")`
for your example :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.mouser.com/")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"aHelp").click()
```

Also for the rest of instructions(for instance XPath , ...) see [this link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'aHelp').click()
```

See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html for details.